# Create date index and add to data frame in R

Tags: r, time-series

Currently transitioning from Python to R. In Python, you can create a date range with pandas and add it to a data frame like so;

```
data = pd.read_csv('Data')
dates = pd.date_range('2006-01-01 00:00', periods=2920, freq='3H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'data' : data}, index = dates)
```

How can I do this in R?

Further, if I want to compare 2 datasets with different lengths but same time span, you can resample the dataset with lower frequency so it can be the same length as the higher frequency by placing 'NaNs' in the holes like so:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('data2') #3 hour resolution = 2920 points of data
data2 = df2.resample('30Min').asfreq() #30 Min resolution = 17520 points
```

I guess I'm basically looking for a Pandas package equivalent for R. How can I code these in R?

Comment: The first part: `seq(from = as.POSIXct("2006-01-01 00:00"), by = "3 hours", length.out = 2920)`

Comment: Are you sure you get `17520` rows after resampling a `2920` row pandas dataframe? Doesn't it return `17515` rows?

Comment: @Abdou that's a good catch, I had to append 5 extra NaNs to that dataframe to make them even

Comment: I cannot think of a quick equivalent of pandas's `resample`, but you can fairly easily write something to do the resampling. I have added an example below as a starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a way of getting your time-series data from a given time interval (3 hours)to another (30 minutes):

Get the data:

```
starter_df <- data.frame(dates=seq(from=(as.POSIXct(strftime("2006-01-01 00:00"))),
                               length.out = 2920, 
                               by="3 hours"),
                     data = rnorm(2920))
```

Get the full sequence in 30 minute intervals and replace the `NA`'s with the values from the `starter_df` data.frame:

```
full_data <- data.frame(dates=seq(from=min(starter_df$dates),
to=max(starter_df$dates), by="30 min"),
data=rep(NA,NROW(seq(from=min(starter_df$dates),
to=max(starter_df$dates), by="30 min"))))

full_data[full_data$dates %in% starter_df$dates,] <- starter_df[starter_df$dates %in% full_data$dates,]
```

I hope it helps.